# How to change key name of an object by comparing another object?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object and another object containing labels, how to write a simple function to compare both array and replace the key name.

```
input = [
 {
"id": "AAP",
"prd": "PL",
"trcode": "NORTH",
"accountNo": "12345",
"prBranch": null,
"prDealer": "Dealer 1",
"prUser": "CFG",
"staticBranch": "YES",
"staticCustomer": "NO",
"reason": "Invalid request"
 },
 {
"id": "AAC",
"prd": "PL",
"trcode": "WEST",
"accountNo": "67890",
"prBranch": null,
"prDealer": "Dealer 2",
"prUser": "DFG",
"staticBranch": "YES",
"staticCustomer": "NO",
"reason": "Invalid request"
 }
],

labels = [
 {
"key": "id",
"value": "USER"
 },
 {
"key": "prd",
"value": "PRODUCT"
 },
 {
"key": "trcode",
"value": "TRANSFER_CODE"
 },
 {
"key": "accountNo",
"value": "ACCOUNT_NUMBER"
 },
 {
"key": "prBranch",
"value": "PROCESSING_BRANCH"
 },
 {
"key": "prDealer",
"value": "PROCESSING_DEALER"
 },
 {
"key": "prUser",
"value": "PROCESSING_USER"
 },
 {
"key": "staticBranch",
"value": "STATIC_BRANCH"
 },
 {
"key": "staticAgent",
"value": "STATIC_AGENT"
 },
 {
"key": "reason",
"value": "Reason"
 }
 ]
```

Expected output  =

```
[
{
"USER": "AAP",
"PRODUCT": "PL",
"TRANSFER_CODE": "NORTH",
"ACCOUNT_NUMBER": "12345",
"PROCESSING_BRANCH": null,
"PROCESSING_DEALER": "Dealer 1",
"PROCESSING_USER": "CFG",
"STATIC_BRANCH": "YES",
"STATIC_CUSTOMER": "NO",
"Reason": "Invalid request"
 },
 {
"USER": "AAC",
"PRODUCT": "PL",
"TRANSFER_CODE": "WEST",
"ACCOUNT_NUMBER": "67890",
"PROCESSING_BRANCH": null,
"PROCESSING_DEALER": "Dealer 2",
"PROCESSING_USER": "DFG",
"STATIC_BRANCH": "YES",
"STATIC_CUSTOMER": "NO",
"Reason": "Invalid request"
 }
 ],
```

Comment: Are you free to modify `labels`? If you can, it would probably simplify your life having something like `labels = { id: 'USER', prd: 'PRODUCT', trcode: 'TRANSFER_CODE', ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert each object in the array. For each object, we can `map` over the entries of the object and use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to look for the replacement key if it exists. Finally, [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) converts the array of key-value pairs back to an object.

```js
let input=[{id:"AAP",prd:"PL",trcode:"NORTH",accountNo:"12345",prBranch:null,prDealer:"Dealer 1",prUser:"CFG",staticBranch:"YES",staticCustomer:"NO",reason:"Invalid request"},{id:"AAC",prd:"PL",trcode:"WEST",accountNo:"67890",prBranch:null,prDealer:"Dealer 2",prUser:"DFG",staticBranch:"YES",staticCustomer:"NO",reason:"Invalid request"}],labels=[{key:"id",value:"USER"},{key:"prd",value:"PRODUCT"},{key:"trcode",value:"TRANSFER_CODE"},{key:"accountNo",value:"ACCOUNT_NUMBER"},{key:"prBranch",value:"PROCESSING_BRANCH"},{key:"prDealer",value:"PROCESSING_DEALER"},{key:"prUser",value:"PROCESSING_USER"},{key:"staticBranch",value:"STATIC_BRANCH"},{key:"staticAgent",value:"STATIC_AGENT"},{key:"reason",value:"Reason"}];
const res = input.map(o => 
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o)
    .map(([k,v])=>[labels.find(({key})=>key===k)?.value ?? k, v])));
console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important;top:0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through `input` and inside the loop use a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to loop through each property.

Inside the loop, loop through `labels` and get the corresponding value to that property, set the value of the property to the new property and delete the previous property.

```js
input.forEach(e => {
  for (const l in e) {
    var a;
    labels.forEach(e => {
      e.key == l && (a = e.value)
    }), e[a] = e[l], delete e[l]
  }
});
```

Demo:

```js
input=[{id:"AAP",prd:"PL",trcode:"NORTH",accountNo:"12345",prBranch:null,prDealer:"Dealer 1",prUser:"CFG",staticBranch:"YES",staticCustomer:"NO",reason:"Invalid request"},{id:"AAC",prd:"PL",trcode:"WEST",accountNo:"67890",prBranch:null,prDealer:"Dealer 2",prUser:"DFG",staticBranch:"YES",staticCustomer:"NO",reason:"Invalid request"}];var labels=[{key:"id",value:"USER"},{key:"prd",value:"PRODUCT"},{key:"trcode",value:"TRANSFER_CODE"},{key:"accountNo",value:"ACCOUNT_NUMBER"},{key:"prBranch",value:"PROCESSING_BRANCH"},{key:"prDealer",value:"PROCESSING_DEALER"},{key:"prUser",value:"PROCESSING_USER"},{key:"staticBranch",value:"STATIC_BRANCH"},{key:"staticAgent",value:"STATIC_AGENT"},{key:"reason",value:"Reason"}];

input.forEach(e=>{for(const l in e){var a;labels.forEach(e=>{e.key==l&&(a=e.value)}),e[a]=e[l],delete e[l]}});

console.log(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the first thing I would to is to use an object instead of an array for your key association:

```js
labels = {
    "id": "USER",
    "prd": "PRODUCT",
    "trcode": "TRANSFER_CODE",
    "accountNo": "ACCOUNT_NUMBER",
    "prBranch": "PROCESSING_BRANCH",
    "prDealer": "PROCESSING_DEALER",
    "prUser": "PROCESSING_USER",
    "staticBranch": "STATIC_BRANCH",
    "staticAgent": "STATIC_AGENT",
    "reason": "Reason"
}
```

Now if you want to map them to your new object you can do

```js
function renameKeys(src) {
  let entries = Object.entries(src)
  let renamedEntries = entries.map(([key, value]) => [
    labels[key] || key,
    /* I added a fallback to the original key
       if it's not found to avoid undefined keys */
    value,
   ])
  return Object.fromEntries(renamedEntries)
}

// and use it like so
console.log(input.map(renameKeys))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate them and assign the values as below

```
for (var object of input) {
  for (var mapping of labels) {
    if (object[mapping.key] !== undefined) {
      object[mapping.value] = object[mapping.key];
      delete object[mapping.key];
    }
  }
}
console.log(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd do it would be:

```js
const input = [{
      "id": "AAP",
      "prd": "PL",
      "trcode": "NORTH",
      "accountNo": "12345",
      "prBranch": null,
      "prDealer": "Dealer 1",
      "prUser": "CFG",
      "staticBranch": "YES",
      "staticCustomer": "NO",
      "reason": "Invalid request"
    },
    {
      "id": "AAC",
      "prd": "PL",
      "trcode": "WEST",
      "accountNo": "67890",
      "prBranch": null,
      "prDealer": "Dealer 2",
      "prUser": "DFG",
      "staticBranch": "YES",
      "staticCustomer": "NO",
      "reason": "Invalid request"
    }
  ];

  const labels = [{
      "key": "id",
      "value": "USER"
    },
    {
      "key": "prd",
      "value": "PRODUCT"
    },
    {
      "key": "trcode",
      "value": "TRANSFER_CODE"
    },
    {
      "key": "accountNo",
      "value": "ACCOUNT_NUMBER"
    },
    {
      "key": "prBranch",
      "value": "PROCESSING_BRANCH"
    },
    {
      "key": "prDealer",
      "value": "PROCESSING_DEALER"
    },
    {
      "key": "prUser",
      "value": "PROCESSING_USER"
    },
    {
      "key": "staticBranch",
      "value": "STATIC_BRANCH"
    },
    {
      "key": "staticAgent",
      "value": "STATIC_AGENT"
    },
    {
      "key": "reason",
      "value": "Reason"
    }
  ]
  
  // 1. create an object mapping the old labels to the new ones
  const betterLabels = labels.reduce((outObj, item) => {
    outObj[item.key] = item.value;
    return outObj;
  }, {});
  
  // 2. use `Array.prototype.map` to traverse the input array
  //    and `Array.prototype.reduce` with the label mapping object
  //    to generate the output array
  const output = input.map(item => {
    return Object.entries(item).reduce((newItem, [key, value]) => {
      betterLabels[key]
        ? newItem[betterLabels[key]] = value
        : newItem[key] = value
      return newItem
    }, {});
  });
  
  //test
  console.log(output);
```